# Detect popover dismiss

Tags: xcode, swift, uikit, uipopover

I know I can use `popoverPresentationControllerDidDismissPopover` but that is only called when the user taps outside the popover view to dismiss it.
When I dismiss the popover manually (`self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)` in the popover's ViewController) nothing happens.

Comment: You can always create a new function that contains the code you need to execute and call it in both `popoverPresentationControllerDidDismissPopover` and where you call `self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)`.

Comment: I can't because I need the code to be executed in the view controller beneath the popover and when I try to do that from the popover I get an error because its referencing an IBOutlet in the first view controller which is nil when the popover is active. I hope you can understand what I mean

Comment: This confused me for a bit too, but the example code at http://stackoverflow.com/a/32021691/708928 with delegates was enlightening and useful for solving this problem.

Answer (score 4):

Popover Dismiss!

There are two ways of detecting popover dismiss:

1. Detecting in `mainViewController`, where it was actually generated, I mean `ParentViewController`.

Using the `parentViewController` as the main generating personal

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource,
UITableViewDelegate, UIPopoverPresentationControllerDelegate {
```

And now implementing these functions:

```
public func adaptivePresentationStyle(for controller: UIPresentationController) -> UIModalPresentationStyle {
    return .none
}

public func popoverPresentationControllerDidDismissPopover(_ popoverPresentationController: UIPopoverPresentationController) {
    print("Popover dismisssed")
}
```

2. Detecting in the controller used to handle `popOverView` made in storyboard.

```
func dismiss() {
    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    print("DISMISSS")
}
    
@IBAction func cancelClicked(_ sender: Any) {
    dismiss()
}
```

NOTE: For storyboards you can ask further details.

Answer (score 0):

Another point is to check if you have any class inherited from your class which also implement the same method of `func popoverPresentationControllerDidDismissPopover(...)`. If so, make sure the upper level class call the base class method like this:

```
 class MyINheritedClass: UIPopoverPresentationControllerDelegate {
   ...
   override func popoverPresentationControllerDidDismissPopover(
       _ popoverPresentationController: UIPopoverPresentationController)
  {
    super.popoverPresentationControllerDidDismissPopover(
        popoverPresentationController) // Make this call 
    ...
   }
}
```

Otherwise, your base level class method will never be called!